# why hibernate query a object from database first before update it

Tags: java, hibernate

I saw a lot of hibernate example and pratical code, that before it updates some objects, it first query them out with their identities, and then sets the attributes that are needed to be updated, I know that query them out will attach the objects to the current open sessions, and update will occur when the transactions associtaed with the sessions are committed. But there are many ways with hibernate that can update a object using its id without querying it out fisrt, for example using hql, there will be one less query and it will be good for performance, then why so many code choose to query it out before update it?

Answer (score 2):

One reasons for this is that bulk operations (`UPDATE` and `DELETE`) are translated into 'pure' SQL and bypass the persistence context.

When updating the entities in the DB directly in this fashion, if the entities in question were already in the persistence context or a cache, they will get stale.

You will then have to invalidate every cache that can contain the affected entities or refetch all potentially affected entities if you want to avoid stale data.